# Show output after preprocess

Tags: c++, c, gcc, msbuild, g++

I have file, with main method and some `#include` directives. I need to generate one file from this file, but without that `#include` directives. That means, that all `#include` will be replaced by that files. I found `g++ -E`, but it also replaces standard libraries.
I need to replace just all relative includes (#include ".."), but not standard includes (#include <...>). Is there a simple way to do this?
It doesn't matter, if it will be in MSBuild or g++.
Reason of this: school
Thank you

Comment: Do you need to do it recursively? That is, do the included files themselves have #includes? Also, do your included files have include guards? Do you include any file more than once? Do you care if it appears more than once in the final output?

Comment: Yes, I need to do it recursively. But also just for relative includes. Included files have include guards, doesnt matter, if in style of "#pragma once" or "#ifndef MYFILE_H_ #define MYFILE_H_". Probably some standart libraries will be included in each class, so some files could be included more times than once. Include more times standart libraries doesnt make sense.